# how to get data from a variable in Def to use it outside and remains updated?

Tags: python-3.x, mqtt, raspberry-pi3

Im trying to make a small 3 connected robots. They have to send and receive sensor data from each other and take an action to make the reads tends to zero again . 
Iam trying to exchange the angle of the movements to let the other one follow him . Iam using the MQTT and it works very well . 
But when i try to get the data from def on_message to use it in the next while the variable isn't global . 
the code as follow :

```
 ############### MQTT section ##################

# when connecting to mqtt do this;
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
 print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
 client.subscribe(sub_topic)

# when receiving a mqtt message do this;

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
 masterangel = int(msg.payload)
 print ( masterangel )



client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(Broker, 1883, 60)
client.loop_start()

# Start the Program
psm.screen.termPrintAt(1, "Press Go to stop program")

while(not doExit):

 oldAngel = Angel

 Angel = gyro.readValue()

 Angelshow = "Current Angel ="+"  "+str (Angel)

 if ( oldAngel != Angel):
   psm.screen.termPrintAt(5, Angelshow)





 if (Angel < masterangel) :
  psm.BBM1.setSpeedSync(20)
  psm.BAM1.floatSync()

 elif (masterangel < Angel ) :
  psm.BAM1.setSpeedSync(20)
  psm.BBM1.floatSync()

  client.publish(pub_topic, "test")
```

now has anyone an Idea how can i use the variable "masterangel" in the while loop ? 
by the way the print order of works fine .

```
  print ( masterangel )
```

thank you in Advance and i appreciate your Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialise the variable outside the scope of the `onMessage` function and then mark it as a global variable in the `onMessage` functions.

Take a look at the python `global` keyword.

```
 ############### MQTT section ##################

# when connecting to mqtt do this;
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
 print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
 client.subscribe(sub_topic)

# when receiving a mqtt message do this;

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
 # use global version not local
 global masterangel
 masterangel = int(msg.payload)
 print ( masterangel )



client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(Broker, 1883, 60)
client.loop_start()

# initialise variable to starting value
masterangel = 0

# Start the Program
psm.screen.termPrintAt(1, "Press Go to stop program")

while(not doExit):

 oldAngel = Angel

 Angel = gyro.readValue()

 Angelshow = "Current Angel ="+"  "+str (Angel)

 if ( oldAngel != Angel):
   psm.screen.termPrintAt(5, Angelshow)





 if (Angel < masterangel) :
  psm.BBM1.setSpeedSync(20)
  psm.BAM1.floatSync()

 elif (masterangel < Angel ) :
  psm.BAM1.setSpeedSync(20)
  psm.BBM1.floatSync()

  client.publish(pub_topic, "test")
```

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly ! Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score -1):

To avoid the problems that may come with scope of variables later on (i.e. mixing local variables with global variables), instead of using the `global` keyword, take advantage of the return statement.

In other words, return allows you to actually use the arguments you pass into the return function and store it into another variable, whereas print() just prints to the screen.

```
############### MQTT section ##################

# when connecting to mqtt do this;
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
 print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
 client.subscribe(sub_topic)

# when receiving a mqtt message do this;

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
 masterangel = int(msg.payload)
 return (masterangel) # Use return() instead of print ()



client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(Broker, 1883, 60)
client.loop_start()

# Start the Program
psm.screen.termPrintAt(1, "Press Go to stop program")


#Assign the value of masterangel being returned by calling the on_message
#function and storing it into its own variable.

new_var = on_message() # This stores the returned value of masterangel


while(not doExit):

 oldAngel = Angel

 Angel = gyro.readValue()

 Angelshow = "Current Angel ="+"  "+str (Angel)

 if ( oldAngel != Angel):
   psm.screen.termPrintAt(5, Angelshow)





 if (Angel < new_var) :
  psm.BBM1.setSpeedSync(20)
  psm.BAM1.floatSync()

 elif (new_var < Angel ) :
  psm.BAM1.setSpeedSync(20)
  psm.BBM1.floatSync()

  client.publish(pub_topic, "test")
```

Comment: That won't work because `on_message` is called by the network loop when a message is delivered from the broker not within the local code,